# How can I render an item from an array with a key

Tags: arrays, react-native

I have an array which stores data according to date, how can I render the data on a particular date?

I tried to use `array[0].Data` and it works, but what I really want to achieve is something like passing a prop "array(Jul)" and it shows the data in Jul. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
let array = [{Month: "Jul", Data: "this is my data", Place: "UK"},{Month: "Aug", Data: "this is my data2", Place: "USA"}] 

<View >
    <Text small bold white> {array(Jul).Data} </Text>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
array.find(x => x.Month === 'Jul').Data
```

Comment: Thank you very simple and easy !!

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the array to an object

```js
let array = [{Month: "Jul", Data: "this is my data", Place: "UK"},{Month: "Aug", Data: "this is my data2", Place: "USA"}] 

const newData = array.reduce((acc, item) => (acc[item.Month] = item.Data, acc),{});

console.log(newData)
console.log(newData['Jul'])
```

and accress to Data like below

```
<View >
    <Text small bold white> {newData['Jul']} </Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Thank you !! That gives me a new idea !!